# cross query Question - (sum & avg)

Tags: database, ms-access-2007

is it possible with cross query to do this ?  (in Access 2007)

I have this table:

50 | A1

60 | A1

70 | B1

80 | B1

90 | C1

I need to get this result:

A1         ------------------               B1        ---------------             C1

sum | avg    -----    sum | avg   -----   sum | avg

55   | 110   ---------     75 | 130   ------         90 | 90

I try to wright this:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Worki.Value) AS XXsum
SELECT Worki.Name AS Name, Worki.Tdate AS Tdate, Worki.ID AS ID
FROM Worki
GROUP BY Worki.Name, Worki.Tdate, Worki.ID
PIVOT Worki.Trit;
```

How I can Get the average and the Sum ?

Answer (score 1):

try like

```sql
select sum(colname),avvg(colname) from tablename group by colname
```

Comment: then what query you are using and what is the table structure do tell us